# CSS: Style a text link in a class

Tags: css

This is a most basic question about formatting text links in css

I have tried to do it myself. I got the hover to work -- at least in firefox.  But can't get the default color to work. Only hover.

Please look at this development page http://ogrowby.com/ in firefox.

There is a menu about the middle of the page, called "Test Menu".   Please click on that.  Then, in the dropdown, go to "TEST LINK".

When you hover over it, the text color changes to Gold. That is fine.  But its default text color is black and I want it to be white.  I may also want to change the font size, etc.  But the main thing is to get the css working to set the default text color for this class to WHITE. `#ffffff`.

Here's my css so far.  The hover is working, but the default remains needs to be changed to `#ffffff`        Only for the `.roundedblue` class.  And it needs to work not only in firefox but other modern browsers.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Rowby

```
.roundedblue:link,
div#Maximenu_NEW_GRANDE ul.maximenuck2 li.roundedblue:hover span.separator {
 color: white;
}

.roundedblue:hover,
div#Maximenu_NEW_GRANDE ul.maximenuck2 li.roundedblue:hover span.separator {
  color: #FFB300;

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: I think you should just remove `:link`.

Comment: How come spans and not anchor tags are used??

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only link you want to change, you should add an id to it and change the id's css properties. If you want multiple elements to have the same properties add a class to the element (if it doesn't already exist).

Then simply edit its properties as you would normally.

```
color:white;
font-size:14px;
...
```

I simply changed the styles in inspector and it worked for me. added "style='color:white;'" to your span.